# Imgproc.convexityDefects(); In eclipse + java + opencv

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, opencv

I need of information about `convexitydefect()` function in Java language.

This is the function:

```
 Imgproc.convexityDefects(MatOfPoint contour, MatOfInt convexhull, MatOfInt4 convexityDefects)
```

The result is in convexityDefects variable:

```
MatOfInt4 convexityDefects;
```

Now in c++ the struct of convexityDefects is:

```
CvPoint* start; // point of the contour where the defect begins

CvPoint* end; // point of the contour where the defect ends

CvPoint* depth_point; // the farthest from the convex hull point within the defect

float depth;
```

But Java retunrs 4 int for row!
How can i get information about start,end,depth_point, depth in java?

Answer (score 0):

The `convexityDefects` structure you mention is for the C API only. For C++ and Java, it's hard to answer better than the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?#convexitydefects) already has:

> In C++ and the new Python/Java interface each convexity defect is represented as 4-element integer vector (a.k.a. `cv::Vec4i`): (`start_index`, `end_index`, `farthest_pt_index`, `fixpt_depth`), where indices are 0-based indices in the original contour of the convexity defect beginning, end and the farthest point, and `fixpt_depth` is fixed-point approximation (with 8 fractional bits) of the distance between the farthest contour point and the hull. That is, to get the floating-point value of the depth will be `fixpt_depth/256.0`.

Thus, `start` and `end` are the first two elements of the 4 `int`s, and contain indices into the `contour`. `depth_point` is the third element, and is the index of the deepest point in `contour`. Divide the last element by 256 to get the floating-point value for the depth.